# Regex match with lookbehind and lookahead with named groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match on the following text:

`"abc" matches "b" and field[cba] = "cba" or (field[cba] matches "c") and "cc" = "bb"`

the parts before and after "matches" into named groups.

I need to match "abc" as `${left}` and "b" as `${right}`, and then "field[cba]" / "c" on the second match.

I need to give bounds to `${left}` and `${right}` so that they break if:

Left:

- should be preceded by any of: `" and "`, `" or "`, `"("` when not in doublequotes (")
- if none of those is present then it could be the start of the string

Right:

- should be followed by any of: `" and "`, `" or "`, `")"` when not in doublequotes (")
- if none of those is present then it could be the end of the string

The replacement regex pattern I would like to use is:

`RegExpMatch(${left}, ${right})`

So to get the following output:

`RegExpMatch("abc","b") and field[cba] = "cba" or (RegExpMatch(field[cba],"c")) and "cc" = "bb"`

I tried with:

`(?<=^|\(| or | and )(?<left>.*?) matches (?<right>.*?)(?=\)|$| and | or )`

This has a couple of issues:

- using `^` for start of string seems to make the lookbehind greedy and it captures from start of string even if there is an `" or "` or `" and "` before, which is weird because `$` seems to work ok
- I don't know how to tell the `" or "`, `" and "`, `"("` or `")"` to match only when not in quotes (in a literal)

Can you please help me in figuring out the correct regular pattern to apply?

Comment: Are you trying to parse an expression?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is it sees `and` in your lookahead, and then you use `.*?` (which will suck up everything until `matches`: `field[cba] = "cba" or (field[cba]`). We need a more strict definition of left/right, it can't just be "any character".

```
(?<=^|\(| or | and )(?<left>\S+) matches (?<right>\S+?)(?=\)|$| and | or )
```

I changed `.*?` to `\S+` which matches anything **but** whitespace (`[^\r\n\t\f ]`).  Now it won't suck up all the unnecessary characters in left/right capture groups.  `\S+` may not be the *right* definition for you, but it should get you started.

Demo: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/nO6tL6)

Comment: I was close to reaching the same conclusion, but you beat me too it. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure how your data is, but I suggest this regex, which is independent of the bounds:

```
(?:(?<left>"[^"]*")|\b(?<left>\S*)) matches (?:(?<right>"[^"]*")|(?<right>\S*[^)\s]))
```

I'm exploiting the fact that C# allows captures with the same name here. The left and right parts are almost the same.

```
(?:            => Non-capture group
  (?<left>     => Left capture begin
    "[^"]*"    => Double quotes, non-quote characters then double quotes
  )            => End left capture 
|              => OR
  \b           => Word boundary
  (?<left>     => Begin other left capture if first failed
    \S*        => Capture non-space characters (if your parts break on multiple lines, you can use [^"]* instead
  )            => End left capture
)              => End non-capture group
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/aL8sJ5) (I changed the named captures because PCRE doesn't support same name capture groups)

If the word boundary is causing problems (e.g. when you have a part that doesn't start with `"` or a `\w` character, you might use the following regex instead:

```
(?:(?<left>"[^"]*")|\s\(?(?<left>\S*)) matches (?:(?<right>"[^"]*")|(?<right>\S*[^)\s]))
```

Which is using `\s\(?` instead of the `\b`

---

If you want to stick to the bounds you mentioned, you will have to know what exactly can be in the parts or what cannot. For instance, if

```
field["abc"] in field matches field["cba"] in field
```

is valid and the parts are `field["abc"] in field` and `field["cba"] in field` respectively, then it's another [complication.](http://regex101.com/r/dG4sV7)